# Chrome Inspect Element adds Quotations

Tags: html, google-chrome, inspect

When I add the code:

```
    <input type=”submit” value=”Save”/>
```

the Chrome inspect element turns the code into this:

```
    <input type="”submit”" value="”Save”/">
```

Why are the extra quotations being added and how can I get it to function properly.

Comment: Use the proper quote marks in the first place?

Comment: The code found in the inspect element uses the "" instead of ''

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation marks are not valid for declaring strings.  You would need to use `"` instead of `”` or remove the quotation marks:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

Comment: Is " not the standard quotation marks on a computer?

Comment: It's a special character.

Comment: @zchbrntmr If the answer was helpful, you should mark it as an accepted answer so that it doesn't appear on the unanswered questions section, people can find the answer easier, etc.